# How to retrieve data from a database and store in a variable Java?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, phpmyadmin

I would like to get data from a database and store in an variable or array. How can I do that? (I'm new on this...)

```
try{
        String sql = "select * from foodtbl where id ='1'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            food.add(rs.getString(sql));
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        }

    }catch (SQLException ex) {
       // Logger.getLogger(mainmenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Call `ex.printStackTrace();` in your `catch` block and add the printed stack to your question.

Comment: Note that the parameter of `rs.getString` is either the index of the column (starting at 1), or the label of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Use `ArrayList<>` to store name from database and later you convert it to `String[]` using `List.toArray()` method.

```
ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
while (rs.next()) {
 list.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Comment: It is still unclear what the OP's issue is. What problem do you think you solved in your answer?